# Dependency Properties not working (making composite behavior)

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm trying to make a composite behavior which is composed of arbitrary simple behaviors. I found behaviors very flexible way of making custom controls.

Currently I have 5 behaviors implemented for slider. but they can conflict with each other.

These behaviors are designed for one control. I could design each of them to work independently without conflicting with each other (its worth mentioning that I did this and it worked successfully. but I removed all of it because it was just ugly.)

There are a lot of share points, I don't want to rewrite same code for every behavior.

So I'm trying to make a composite behavior for one control. this behavior has some attached properties which is shared for all of its containing behaviors. therefor these behaviors don't conflict with each other. And also a lot of code redundancy is gone. now containing behaviors becomes a lot simpler.

Here is the XAML sample for you to better get the idea.

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <b:SliderCompositeBehavior SourceValue="{Binding SharedValue}">
        <sb:FreeSlideBehavior/>
        <sb:LockOnDragBehavior/>
        <sb:CancellableDragBehavior/>
        <sb:KeepRatioBehavior/>
        <sb:DragCompletedCommandBehavior Command="{Binding SeekTo}"/>
    </b:SliderCompositeBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Also all of these behaviors are designed to work stand alone. i.e putting it like this works just fine.

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <sb:FreeSlideBehavior/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Here is `CompositeBehavior<T> : Behavior<T>` :

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(BehaviorCollection))]
public abstract class CompositeBehavior<T> : Behavior<T>
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BehaviorCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            $"{nameof(CompositeBehavior<T>)}<{typeof(T).Name}>",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<Behavior<T>>),
            typeof(CompositeBehavior<T>),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.NotDataBindable));

    public ObservableCollection<Behavior<T>> BehaviorCollection
    {
        get
        {
            var collection = GetValue(BehaviorCollectionProperty) as ObservableCollection<Behavior<T>>;

            if (collection == null)
            {
                collection = new ObservableCollection<Behavior<T>>();
                collection.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
                SetValue(BehaviorCollectionProperty, collection);
            }

            return collection;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // some code to throw exception when same behavior is set more than once.
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        foreach (var behavior in BehaviorCollection)
        {
            behavior.Attach(AssociatedObject);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        foreach (var behavior in BehaviorCollection)
        {
            behavior.Detach();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `SliderCompositeBehavior : CompositeBehavior<Slider>` (only one dependency is shown for sake of simplicity)

```
public sealed class SliderCompositeBehavior : CompositeBehavior<Slider>
{
    private Slider Host => AssociatedObject;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(SourceValue),
            typeof(double),
            typeof(SliderCompositeBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                0d,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                OnSourceValueChanged));

    // does the binding
    public double SourceValue
    {
        get { return (double)Host.GetValue(SourceValueProperty); }
        set { Host.SetValue(SourceValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // attached property for containing behaviors.
    public static void SetSourceValue(Slider host, double value)
    {
        host.SetValue(SourceValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetSourceValue(Slider host)
    {
        return (double)host.GetValue(SourceValueProperty);
    }

    private static void OnSourceValueChanged(DependencyObject dpo, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var soruce = (SliderCompositeBehavior)dpo;

        soruce.Host.Value = (double)args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

Now there are two problems I can see.

- Dependency property definitions inside containing behaviors do not function at all.
- Overrinding metadata of dependency property does not work for containing properties.

Inside `DragCompletedCommandBehavior : Behavior<Slider>` I have

```
public sealed class DragCompletedCommandBehavior : Behavior<Slider>
{
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Command),
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(DragCompletedCommandBehavior));
}
```

I get this error on output. (this does not throw exception. it was hidden somewhere in output display after program started.)

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=SeekTo; DataItem=null; target element is 'DragCompletedCommandBehavior' (HashCode=52056421); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

In another behavior I have this.

```
public sealed class LockOnDragBehavior : Behavior<Slider>
{
    static LockOnDragBehavior()
    {
        SliderCompositeBehavior.SourceValueProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(LockOnDragBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                0d,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                OnSourceValueChanged));
    }

    private static void OnSourceValueChanged(DependencyObject dpo, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But `OnSourceValueChanged` never fires. the main `OnSourceValueChanged` inside `SliderCompositeBehavior` still fires though. but new meta data is just doing nothing.

How can I fix these problems? I don't understand why Dependency properties inside containing behaviors does not work. can some one please explain why? Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes. but as I said, these behaviors can conflict with each other if I add them directly. I was able to do what you say. but every behavior would become a lot larger. because I have to write same thing for each behavior. for example `Thumb` property which is shared. or some other properties that I use to sync these behaviors with.

Comment: slow learner here.. now got.

Comment: @WPFUser got it fixed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it out. [after reading this post](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) I understood that elements (in my case nested behaviors) were not part of the visual or logical tree. So data context was not accessible. and therefor binding did not work.

But instead of using `ProxyBinding` [which was used here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) I came up with better solution.

The special collection `BehaviorCollection` does some magic when attaching behaviors. but I was using `ObservableCollection` therfor behaviors did not attached correctly.

Unfortunately the constructor of `BehaviorCollection` is internal. But who cares when you have power of reflection? ;)

Using `BehaviorCollection` instead essentially fixed the binding problem.

how ever overriding metadata problem is still not fixed. but I guess I will try other approaches (like using another dependency property) rather than overriding metadata of dependency property.

Here is the correction to `CompositeBehavior<T>` class.

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(BehaviorCollection))]
public abstract class CompositeBehavior<T> : Behavior<T>
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    #region Behavior Collection

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BehaviorCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            $"{nameof(CompositeBehavior<T>)}<{typeof(T).Name}>",
            typeof(BehaviorCollection),
            typeof(CompositeBehavior<T>),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.NotDataBindable));

    public BehaviorCollection BehaviorCollection
    {
        get
        {
            var collection = GetValue(BehaviorCollectionProperty) as BehaviorCollection;

            if (collection == null)
            {
                var constructor = typeof(BehaviorCollection)
                    .GetConstructor(
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                        null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);

                collection = (BehaviorCollection) constructor.Invoke(null);
                collection.Changed += OnCollectionChanged;
                SetValue(BehaviorCollectionProperty, collection);
            }

            return collection;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var hashset = new HashSet<Type>();
        foreach (var behavior in BehaviorCollection)
        {
            if (behavior is Behavior<T> == false)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{behavior.GetType()} does not inherit from {typeof(Behavior<T>)}.");
            }
            if (hashset.Add(behavior.GetType()) == false)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{behavior.GetType()} is set more than once.");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    protected sealed override void OnAttached()
    {
        OnSelfAttached();
        foreach (var behavior in BehaviorCollection)
        {
            behavior.Attach(AssociatedObject);
        }
    }

    protected sealed override void OnDetaching()
    {
        OnSelfDetaching();
        foreach (var behavior in BehaviorCollection)
        {
            behavior.Detach();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnSelfAttached()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void OnSelfDetaching()
    {
    }
}
```